# Regex matches whole lines for delimited row input - except when line has a dollar sign in it

Tags: regex, csv

```
Regex TempSplitter = 
    new Regex(
    "[^\"\r\n$]*(\r\n|\n|$)|(([^\"\r\n$]*)(\"[^\"]*\")([^\"\r\n$]*))*(\r\n|\n|$)"
    );
```

Sample input:

```
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith2,1,Jacob2,$1.00,300,555-50-0002
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith8,1,Jacob8,$2.00,900,555-50-0008
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith6,1,Jacob6,$3.00,700,555-50-0006
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith4,1,Jacob4,$4.00,500,555-50-0004
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith0,1,Jacob0,$5.00,100,555-50-0000
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith3,1,Jacob3,$6.00,400,555-50-0003
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith5,1,Jacob5,$7.00,600,555-50-0005
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith1,1,Jacob1,$8.00,200,555-50-0001
US,12345,AL,Ashton,123 Fake St #1,Smith7,1,Jacob7,$9.00,800,555-50-0007
```

The matches only match from the `$` on and not any of the text before it.
When I remove the `$` it matches the whole line as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unquoted pattern parts exclude `$` (the `[^\"\r\n$]` patterns), and the other `$`s are unquoted and therefore mean "end of line".  So the only way this will accept `$` is between `"` characters.

Comment: well the `[^\"\r\n$]` is specifically to match end of line or end of stream. So it should continue to match the entire thing, right?

Comment: `$` is literal inside brackets; you can't match end of line/stream that way.  (More specifically, `[]` matches character lists/ranges.  It can't match patterns or anchors.)

Comment: So removing them seems to work :) Seems strange though, I could have sworn it was fine. I'll test this with more test data but so far I think you're right :)